# Арифметические операции между двумя dt.time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, время, datetime

имеется два поля:

```
a = '20-10-2019 12:11:00'
b = '10:00:05'
```

необходимо выполнить операцию 
`a.time() - b`, но возникает ошибка:

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and
>   'datetime.time'.

Как можно выполнять подобные вычисления? их необходимо будет применять на датафрейме

Пример данных:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame([['C102', 'Stage1','20-10-2019 12:11:00','10:00:05'], ['C116','Stage1','16-08-2019 16:12:17','6:10:12'], ['D285','Stage2','27-09-2019 15:47:22','13:00:56']], columns=['IDOper', 'Stage','a','b'])`
```

функция должна сработать по примеру:

```
def Time(row):
    row['c']=row['a'].time() - row['b']

df.apply(Time, axis = 1)
```

Comment: Дополнила вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно получить в качестве результата разницу во времени без компонента даты (т.е. объект типа `timedelta`):

```
df["res"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["a"].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')) \
            - pd.to_timedelta(df['b'])
```

если же столбец `a` содержит строки, а не `datetime` то:

```
df["res"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["a"].str.split().str[1]) \
            - pd.to_timedelta(df['b'])
```

---

результат:

```
In [134]: df
Out[134]:
  IDOper   Stage                   a         b      res
0   C102  Stage1 2019-10-20 12:11:00  10:00:05 02:10:55
1   C116  Stage1 2019-08-16 16:12:17   6:10:12 10:02:05
2   D285  Stage2 2019-09-27 15:47:22  13:00:56 02:46:26

In [135]: df.dtypes
Out[135]:
IDOper             object
Stage              object
a          datetime64[ns]
b                  object
res       timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['C102', 'Stage1','20-10-2019 12:11:00','10:00:05'], ['C116','Stage1','16-08-2019 16:12:17','6:10:12'], ['D285','Stage2','27-09-2019 15:47:22','13:00:56']], columns=['IDOper', 'Stage','a','b'])

df['a']=pd.to_datetime(df['a'], errors='coerce') # переводим в datetime
df['res']=df['a'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['b'], unit='h')
print(df)
```

Получаем

```
    IDOper  Stage   a          b                    res
0   C102    Stage1  2019-10-20 12:11:00 10:00:05    2019-10-20 02:10:55
1   C116    Stage1  2019-08-16 16:12:17 6:10:12     2019-08-16 10:02:05
2   D285    Stage2  2019-09-27 15:47:22 13:00:56    2019-09-27 02:46:26
```

Comment: по-моему параметр `unit` нужен только для числовых значений...